# Android listview item animation not work if there is no scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

I have listView in activity.
In row there is one button and Textview. when we click on button I need to replace textview text with flip animation. But this animation is not working. if there is more like (if there is some scroll available in listview) then animation working fine using same code. Also in os version lower then 5.0 its working fine.

I observed this problem os version 5.0 and higher version

Comment: put code with out it how any one give solution

Comment: @VishalThakkar Sorry for not sharing code. Actually I tried to explain issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue.
Actually ListView have issue with animation if we using wrap_content property with ListView.

I took reference from following answer. [ListView animation bug on item click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791955/listview-animation-bug-on-item-click)